# How do I define Credentials as params in Jenkinsfile scripted pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am defining a scripted pipeline with many inputs, 2 of them are credentials. In the UI I can see how to add an input that is a credential, but I can't find anything on how to define Credential Params for scripted Pipelines. My params are defined like:

```
properties([
  buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '20')),
  parameters([
     stringParam(name: 'export_credentials'),
     stringParam(name: 'import_credentials'),
  ]),
])
```

But I'd prefer it to be actual credentials params and not string ones

Comment: It appears that the actual parameter should be the name of the credential, and not the credential itself. You probably want to modify the parameter to be a string that is the name of the credential, and then utilize that to perform the credential lookup within the pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out after exploring the job-dsl plugin API (<jenkins_url>/plugin/job-dsl/api-viewer/index.htm):

```
properties([
  buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '20')),
  disableResume(),
  parameters([
     credentials(name: 'export_token_credential_id', required: true, credentialType: "com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl", defaultValue: 'dockerjenkins-token', description: 'Username and API Token for the Jenkins to migrate from'),
     credentials(name: 'import_token_credential_id', required: true, credentialType: "com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl", defaultValue: 'cloudbees-token', description: 'Username and API Token for this Jenkins'),
     stringParam(name: 'item', description: 'Item (job) to migrate. '),
     choiceParam(name: 'disable_mode', choices: "NEITHER\nDEST\nSOURCE\nBOTH", description: 'Which Jenkins, if any, to disable jobs on when migrating'),
  ]),
])
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep the string secured use the following:

```
properties([
   buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '20')),
   parameters([
       password(description: 'b', name: 'b')
   ])
])
```